# Woocommerce plugin causing redirect

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes, construction

i'm using woocommerce to create a store for my shop in WordPress but whenever I activate the woocommerce plugin the page redirect with this message "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS", then when I deactivate the page works. please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There could be several reasons that would cause this, but if you're able to, I'd try activating WooCommerce, then going to the Settings > Permalinks page and saving (with no changes)

Comment: Tried your suggestion but didn't work.

Comment: Does the entire site have the too many redirects error, or just certain pages?

Comment: The entire site